# Set number of author only for parencite biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, author-number

I'm using `biblatex` for my bibliography with the author-year style. 
I'd like to have only one author when using `\parencite`, e.g. (Anderson et al. 2009). But I want to show all the names in the Bibliography.

I tried the `maxnames=1` option, but it works for both.
How can I do?

This are the option for my `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,sortcites=true,firstinits=true,%
            doi=false,url=false,isbn=false, hyperref]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the option `maxcitenames=1` and not `maxnames=1`.

`maxcitenames` affects only the citations in the document body, `maxbibnames` affects only the bibliography and `maxnames` affects both.

So, load `biblatex` in this way:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxcitenames=1,sortcites=true,%
            firstinits=true,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,%
            hyperref]{biblatex}
```